# Access JSON response from RequestBuilder

Tags: java, gwt

Might be a dumb question but how can I retrieve the value of the response given by the RequestBuilder in a JSON format. My code is this:

```
try {
          Request request = builder.sendRequest(json, new RequestCallback() {
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                System.out.println("CAN'T CONNECT");
               // Couldn't connect to server (could be timeout, SOP violation, etc.)
            }

            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
              if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                  System.out.println("SUCCESS");
                  System.out.println(response.getText());
                  // Process the response in response.getText()
              } else {
                  System.out.println("ERROR" + response.getStatusCode() + response.getText());
                // Handle the error.  Can get the status text from response.getStatusText()
              }
            }
          });
        } catch (RequestException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Currently, the response gives me {faceAmount: 29921}. How do I access the value for faceAmount and store it to a variable? Is the response providing me with a JSON format or just straight up text string?

Comment: There is some stuff in docs that might be useful : http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSON.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `com.google.gwt.json.client`, or use JSNI and overlay types, or better, use JsInterop. You'll find more in the docs: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSON.html, http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON.html, http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJsInterop.html

```
@JsType(isNative=true)
interface Response {
  @JsProperty int getFaceAmount();
}

Response r = (Response) (JavaScriptObject) JsonUtils.parse(json);
```